# Is there a pandas operation that allows me to fill Nan values with a categorical MultiIndex Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

Below is the general form of the Dataframe

[screen shot of Hierarchical Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqdFG.png)

Is there a solution to where I could replace those Nan values with the column values of the same 'Order ID' Index?

I've already tried `pd.melt` and `pd.pivot` to try to tidy this data, where it seems already tidy, just with missing values I'm needing to reformat.

Comment: Please see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and then [edit] your question accordingly.